# How to build an intuition for Servant's type-errors?

Tags: haskell, servant

I'm stuck with the following error, after a major code refactor:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘Endpoint.AuditLog.Routes
                             (AsServerT (AppM '[] ()))’
      with

      --
      -- complete API type comes here
      --

      Expected type: ServerT Routes (AppM '[] ())
        Actual type: Endpoint.AuditLog.Routes (AsServerT (AppM '[] ()))
    • In the expression: (Endpoint.AuditLog.server appRunners)
      In an equation for ‘prodServer’:
          prodServer = (Endpoint.AuditLog.server appRunners)
```

I've read, and re-read [the documentation](https://docs.servant.dev/en/stable/cookbook/generic/Generic.html), but cannot seem to find where the error is. This code was working earlier, and I've changed `Endpoint.AuditLog.server :: Routes (AsServerT AppM)` to `Endpoint.AuditLog.server :: AppRunners m n -> Routes (AsServerT n)` and confirmed that the type of the following expressions seems to be similar across the refactor; basically `Routes (AsServerT AppM)` has changed to `Routes (AsServerT (AppM '[] ()))`

```
ghci> :t (Endpoint.AuditLog.server AppM.appRunners)
(Endpoint.AuditLog.server AppM.appRunners) :: Routes (AsServerT (AppM '[] ()))
```

The following snippet is also *structurally* the same across the refactor:

```
type Routes = (ToServant Endpoint.AuditLog.Routes AsApi)

prodServer :: ServerT Routes (AppM '[] ())
prodServer = (Endpoint.AuditLog.server AppM.appRunners)
```

How do I go about debugging this error? Since there are a lot of type-families involved, is there any way to see what the following type-level expressions simplify to:

- `ServerT Routes (AppM '[] ())`
- `Endpoint.AuditLog.Routes (AsServerT (AppM '[] ()))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expletive! Expletive! Expletive!

I was missing a `toServant` -

```
prodServer :: ServerT Routes (AppM '[] ())
prodServer = (toServant $ Endpoint.AuditLog.server AppM.appRunners)
```

Comment: That's fine. You solved the problem. Mark it correct. :)